# AWS Cognito Integration in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, amazon-cognito, php-5.6, php-7.1

We are trying to use [AWS - Cognito](https://github.com/pmill/aws-cognito) with our PHP Version 5.6 but it seems like there is no library which works for our PHP version which we are trying to use.

The reason we are trying to use this library in older PHP version, because we have an ongoing project which is already made in PHP Version 5.6 and if we try to switch this project into PHP Version 7.1 then we are getting lots of errors which is not compatible and feasible to latest PHP Version 7.1 and we can't change the code at this situation hence we are trying to make this library somehow work in our PHP version 5.6.

Can someone guide me how can I make this library work?

Comment: The requirements page for that library clearly states that it's for PHP 7.1 or later. So, probably nobody will be able to help you get it working with PHP 5.6. You may need to instead update your CakePHP application, I think you would need to go to at least version 3.4 to get PHP 7.1 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the official [aws-sdk-php package](https://packagist.org/packages/aws/aws-sdk-php) directly that the [pmill/aws-cognito package](https://packagist.org/packages/pmill/aws-cognito) also uses. The documentation for the package is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-cognito-idp-2016-04-18.html).

To get started quickly, you could basically just look at the  [pmill/aws-cognito package](https://packagist.org/packages/pmill/aws-cognito)'s [source](https://github.com/pmill/aws-cognito/blob/master/src/CognitoClient.php) and copy what they have done. The only part of that package that is incompatible with php 5.6 is the [web-token/jwt-signature package](https://packagist.org/packages/web-token/jwt-signature) that they use to decode an access token in the `decodeAccessToken` [function](https://packagist.org/packages/web-token/jwt-signature). You should be able to just change that function to use a php 5.6 compatible jwt package like [lcobucci/jwt](https://packagist.org/packages/lcobucci/jwt#3.2.5) if you ever do have the need to decode the access token.